# Windows 10 keeps 'finding' my external drives

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I installed Windows 10 (version 1067, 14393.693). As of a few days, it keeps "discovering" my external drives, which were installed together with the OS some 2 weeks ago. At about two-minute intervals, an Explorer window appears for first the G: drive, then the F: drive, and so on ad nauseam.

These windows steal focus and gum up the works to the point where I had to turn off the drives by their power switches to write this post uninterrupted.

How do I correct whatever is causing Windows 10 to do this?

Comment: There isn't much diagnostic information here for people to go on.  Given the sudden start of symptoms after running normally, it could be some form of corruption or even a hardware problem.  It's tough to diagnose these kinds of issues on a Q&A site that's designed around questions that have a "right answer" that is knowable from the information presented.  I believe that your 6 rep is enough to interact on the Root Access chat room, accessible from the Chat link at the bottom.  You might be able to get some diagnostic help there.